# Reading one line at a time in C

Tags: c, file

Which method can be used to read one line at a time from a file in C?

I am using the **fgets** function, but it's not working.
It's reading the space separated token only.

What to do?

Comment: So you don't really want to read a line, you want to read up until a space is encountered?  Or are you saying that fgets is stopping on spaces instead of newlines?

Comment: should stop on new line character only.

Comment: Here is my Input::
START
A DC 10
B DS 20
STOP

I got::
START
A
B
STOP
as my output..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work, when you can't use `fgets()` for some reason.

```
int readline(FILE *f, char *buffer, size_t len)
{
   char c; 
   int i;

   memset(buffer, 0, len);

   for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {   
      int c = fgetc(f); 

      if (!feof(f)) 
      {   
         if (c == '\r')
            buffer[i] = 0;
         else if (c == '\n')
         {   
            buffer[i] = 0;

            return i+1;
         }   
         else
            buffer[i] = c; 
      }   
      else
      {   
         //fprintf(stderr, "read_line(): recv returned %d\n", c);
         return -1; 
      }   
   }   

   return -1; 
}
```

Comment: thanx buddy its wokring but still I have a problem..
My buffer is reading and storing entire line
but while printing its printing only first space separted token only

Comment: That's strange, I can just use `printf("%s\n", buffer);` and it outputs the whole buffer

Comment: yeh,
its strange for me also. because it was working for all previous programs... :'(

Comment: Are you sure that your file does not contain any string terminators?

Answer (score 19):

Use the following program for getting the line by line from a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
  char filename[] = "file.txt";
  FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

  if (file != NULL) {
    char line [1000];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
      fprintf(stdout,"%s",line); //print the file contents on stdout.
    }

    fclose(file);
  }
  else {
    perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `fgets` function will read a single line from a file or `num` characters where `num` is the second parameter passed to `fgets`.  Are you passing a big enough number to read the line?

For Example

```
// Reads 500 characters or 1 line, whichever is shorter
char c[500];
fgets(c, 500, pFile);
```

Vs.

```
// Reads at most 1 character
char c;
fgets(&c,1,pFile);
```

Comment: @JaredPar: Cool! You fixed it! :P Hey, I upvoted after downvoting from 0 to -1, then upvoted as you rectified it, to bring it back up to zero, instead it jumped to 1...is that my browser or a glitch?

Comment: @t0mm13b To revert your downvote, click the downvote button again. Downvote then upvote != neither downvote nor upvote.

Answer (score 8):

If you are coding for a platform that has the GNU C library available, you can use getline():

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Comment: That function is also available in BSD systems, just for information ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment than a complete answer, but I don't have enough points to comment. :)

Here's the function prototype for fgets():

```
char *fgets(char *restrict s, int n, FILE *restrict stream);
```

It will read n-1 bytes or up to a newline or eof.  For more info see [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html)

Answer (score 2):

`fgets()` should be the way to go …

Comment: as long as the buffer is big enough

Comment: Tom:  That's what the second parameter is for, to avoid overrunning the buffer.  Or do you mean not foreseeing a big enough buffer?  IIRC, my C compiler has a 512 byte limit on individual lines.

Comment: Which C compiler is that?. And I'm thinking on the case where you dont know how long the line is, e.g stdin. Not trying to  start a holy war on this.

Answer (score 2):

use either `fgets` if you know that your lines will fit into buffer or use `fgetc` for more control over reading

Answer (score 2):

Use `fgets` to read from the line, and then use `getc(...)` to chew up the newline or end-of-line to continue reading....here's an example of forever reading a line...

```
// Reads 500 characters or 1 line, whichever is shorter
char c[500], chewup;
while (true){
    fgets(c, sizeof(c), pFile);
    if (!feof(pFile)){
        chewup = getc(pFile); // To chew up the newline terminator
        // Do something with C
    }else{
        break; // End of File reached...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Source of Error:

Actually it was not my fault..
In this case .
I was using strtok function and and accidently modified my original my original string.
Hence while printing I was getting the error...

Thanks Everyone for Helping me.. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use fscanf instead of fgets. Because fgets fscanf for characters including spaces but while using fscanf you can separately access to data saved in a file.eg there be a file having name class roll.now declare a string and two integers line.