# How do I extract a specific numbered line from a text file? (C)

Tags: c, string, file

I am trying to write a function that prints a specific line from a text file based on the number given. For example, let's say the file contains the following:

```
1 hello1 one
2 hello2 two
3 hello3 three
```

If the number given is '3', the function will output "hello3 three". If the number given is '1', the function output will be "hello1 one".

I am very new to C but here is my logic so far.

I imagine first thing is first, I need to find the character 'number' inside the file. Then what? How do I go about writing the line out without including the number? How do I even find the 'number'? I am sure it's very simple but I have no idea how to do this. Here is what I have so far:

```
void readNumberedLine(char *number)
{
    int size = 1024;
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    char *line;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("xxxxx.txt", "r");
    while(fp != NULL && fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL)
    {
      if(line = strstr(buffer, number))
      //here is where I am confused as to what to do.           
    }
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
            fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Per the problem definition, I thought you want the 3rd line irrespective of the content. However, your solution seem to find the line that contains "3". Which one do you want?

Comment: @Arun, I think he want the 3rd line, but he wrote a code with unexpected result to achieve that goal.

Comment: Sorry, If the parameter is '1' then it will be "hello1 one" etc. If the parameter is '2' then the contents of the same line after "2 " will be printed.

Comment: Can a line be, `hello5 six`? If so, what happens when the input is 5 or 6?

Comment: @Anish There would have to be an error if the number 5 or 6 is not found in the file. However, if the numbered lines of 5 or 6 are included in the file then that line will be printed (without the tag).  I hope it made sense.

Comment: @GigaTocka  my answer will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what you are saying you are looking for lines tagged with a number at the beginning of the line.  In which case you want something where you can read a line with a tag prefix

```
bool readTaggedLine(char* filename, char* tag, char* result)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(f == NULL) return false;
    while(fgets(result, 1024, f))
    {
        if(strncmp(tag, result, strlen(tag))==0)
        {
            strcpy(result, result+strlen(tag)+1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then use it like

```
char result[3000];
if(readTaggedLine("blah.txt", "3", result))
{
    printf("%s\r\n", result);
}
else
{
    printf("Could not find the desired line\r\n");
}
```

Comment: That is really clever, I didn't even think of incorporating a boolean function. Also, using strncmp() like you did is a lot simpler. Thank you!

Comment: I much prefer passing things in.   Especially with memory allocation.  I prefer to pass buffers,  so that means you can use it with malloc or static memory as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following.

Approach 1:

```
Read and throw away (n - 1) lines 
// Consider using readline(), see reference below
line = readline() // one more time
return line
```

Approach 2:

```
Read block by block and count carriage-return characters (e.g. '\n'). 
Keep reading and throwing away for the first (n - 1) '\n's
Read characters till next '\n' and accumulate them into line
return line
```

readline(): [Reading one line at a time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372813/reading-one-line-at-a-time-in-c)

P.S. Following is a shell solution, it may be used to unit test the C program.

```
// Display 42nd line of file foo
$ head --lines 42 foo | tail -1
// (head displays lines 1-42, and tail displays the last of them)
```

Comment: I was going to go with Approach 2 but I am sure you would agree that it is really tedious. Thank you for the input, there are so many ways to solve this problem.

Comment: It is, but the problem definition was confusing :-), I tried to clarify by asking in the question's comment section, but I clearly failed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional value to help you record how many lines you have read.Then in `while` loop compare the value with your input value, if they are equal, output the `buffer`.