# remove characters from EOL

Tags: c, linux, newline

I read a buffer from a serial device. It returns me these results (2 lines every time)

```
Hello World.
My name is John.

Hello World.^M^JMy name 
is Mike.

Hello World.^M^JMy name 
is ^M^JERROR Peter.
```

These results are in Linux command line. ^M^J is the EOL and means \r\n in Windows. The first result is ok but the other two are terrible. Is there any way to check for ^M^J characters and remove them? Because I want these results:

```
Hello World.
My name is John.

Hello World.
My name is Mike.

Hello World.
My name is Peter.
```

With this code I read the buffer

```
char buff[150];
memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
for (;;)
{
  n=read(fd,buff,sizeof(buff));
  printf("%s", buff);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I open and configure my device in this way

```
int open_port(void)
{
int fd; // file description for the serial port 
fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if(fd == -1) // if open is unsucessful
{
 //perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyAMA0 - ");
 printf("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyAMA0. \n");
}
else
{
  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
  printf("port is open.\n");
}

return(fd);
} //open_port
```

And configure port

```
int configure_port(int fd)      // configure the port
{
 struct termios port_settings;      // structure to store the port settings in
 cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B9600);    // set baud rates
 cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B9600);
 port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // set no parity, stop bits, data bits
 port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
 port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
 port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;
 tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);    // apply the settings to the port
 return(fd);

} //configure_port
```

Comment: I think you will have to check char by char for ascii value http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart

Comment: whats happens in windows after you `read()` an EOF ? does read stop ?

Comment: I don't know what happens in Windows. I use Linux and I have these characters

Comment: @mf_ Clearly EOF was a typo for EOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `printf()` is behaving in an interesting fashion when it sees a `\r\n` rather than a lone `\n`.  It interprets the paired character end-of-line as not an end-of-line and so  rather than doing the usual end-of-line-function, it shows you a `^M^J`.  Simple eliminating the `\r` will then give you the desired behavior.

```
  char buff[150];
  int n = read(fd,buff,sizeof(buff));  // buff is not NUL terminated
  if (n < 0) {
    // deal with I/O error
    }
  if (n == 0) {
    // deal with end-of-file
    }
  else {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      if (isprint(buff[i]) || (buff[i] == '\n')) {
        putchar(buff[i]);
      }
      else if (buff[i] == '\r') {
        ; // drop it
      }
      else {
        ; // TBD deal with unexpected control codes and codes 127-255
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Notes:
1) You filled `buff` before from the serial device using a `read()`.  As serial devices are binary, the bytes read may include NUL bytes.  Reading an array of bytes with sporadically intersperse NUL bytes in a buffer and treating it like a NUL terminated character string will lead to missed data.
2) A `read()` does not append a `\0` byte to the end of the buffer it reads and may explain your "ERROR".
3) In general, you are reading a binary device and writing to a textual output.  The incoming binary stream is likely ASCII text using `\r\n` as an end-of-line but your `stdout` wants to use `\n` as end-of-line.  As long as the bytes are printable ASCII (codes 32-126), all works as expected when printing to `stdout`.  But when you read a `\0`, `\r`, `\n`, paired `\r\n`, other control characters, communication errors, etc., you need to consider how you want that displayed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I updated the post with open and configure functions which I wrote

Comment: One question, because I get fd as int, can I use it with fgets?I think no!

Comment: I see that in your update and will amend my answer. (Should have seen it in the original `read()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `^M^J` are end of line, not end of file.

Secondly, `read` reads binary data from the specified file descriptor. It reads the number of characters you have specified till it reaches the end of the file, or gets an error. If you want to read lines at a time, read one byte at a time, or use some other line oriented I/O calls (sscanf, that sort of thing)

Comment: Our, knock my head, Answer deleted, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372813/reading-one-line-at-a-time-in-c) question, which proposes a function for reading lines from a file and dealing with Windows' carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with `O_TEXT`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_TEXT);
```

Comment: With this solution(with this header) I have error: 'O_TEXT' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Either 1) `O_TEXT` is in an include file such as `<rsync.h>`, `<io.h>`, `<fcntl.h>`, or 2) `<sys/stat.h>` or your are using a Unix-like system that does not differentiate between binary and text files.  If #2 is the case and the unit originating the message is PC-like, then _it_ should use the O_TEXT flag.