# Editing a specific row in txt file using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a text files, the data in text file is;

file1.txt

```
1.0|BWP
1.0|KWK
1.0|RLS
1.0|KPP
```

I want to edit row no 3 to

```
2.0|RLS
```

Kindly help me how can i achieve this;

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and what specific problem you are having.

Comment: Are all the rows the same length? Do you know how to open the file for editting?

Comment: Will this help? This is not C++. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372813/reading-one-line-at-a-time-in-c

Comment: @doctorlove yes the rows length are same, i can open the file for editing

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you have simple ASCII encoding, you can compute the position of every line in your file. Each line is either 8 or 9 characters long (depending on what line terminator you use). Let that number be stored in variable `len`. So the solution is this:

1. Open the file
2. Jump to line `x` (e.g. `x = 2`, note that the first row is `x = 0`) by seeking to position `x * len`
3. Write new line of **exactly** `len` bytes (e.g. `char[len]`)
4. Close file, if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I don't like this approach because the question is labeled `c++` and assuming ASCII encoding is the same as my magic number. It is not a really good practice. And you can't even tell how long is the line =). Better but similar would be to read and discard lines one by one. If you get to work with unicode or something more fancy than ASCII it will easily break. Predicting the position is not always that easy. Heck here it is not. You cannot do it. Also if the line length changed it would break. It is a matter of one's needs. This will certainly be faster in execution.

Answer (score 1):

**A little disclaimer**

I hope I won't get too much bashing for degrading SO quality. But this was too long for a comment.

Generally you should ask here questions that can have precise answer, and/or solve a specific (technical more or less) problem. Not "I'm alone in the dark. Halp plox." This is why people are strongly encouraged to show what they did try.

However, I get the feeling the OP have absolutely no clue where to start and thinks there is some paradigm or built-in support in standard library for his task. I believe in their goodwill and trust its better to give an idea than let them run into wilderness, just to try something to be eligible to ask a question on SO. I want to give some hints and starters. I hope this is acceptable and will help him to break problem into several specific problems/questions, that can actually be precisely answered.

**Answer attempt:**

Well there is no default go-to way for manipulating text files like in a text editor. This is quite a non-trivial task when you start breaking it down to what you can actually do in language.

The general approach for your kind of problem is to read the file into memory and store it as a separate lines. More over, it seems that you can parse each line, and make a *model* for each line. I would start with:

```
class Line{
public:
  Line(const std::string& text_line); // parse an actual line
  Line();
  std::string to_string(); // return textual representation for saving

  void set_value1(float);
  float get_value1();
  void set_value2(const std::string&);
  const std::string& get_value2();
private:
  float value1;
  std::string value2;
};
```

Make `Document` a collection of `Line`s. And you can pretty much freely manipulate it. I hope this is good for starters. You need to figure out how to load up a file line by line, and how to write `ctor` and `to_string()` but this should be way easier to seek help for in case of troubles.

If you think this is an overkill. Maybe. But the question could be answered:

1. set magic_number to 17
2. open file
3. seek(magic_number)
4. write 2
5. close file

I hope i got the `magic_number` ok =).

Comment: Why would you want to store the file in memory, if you only want to change a single line? Also note that "magic numbers" (i.e. unnamed, unexplained constants) are bad programming practice and in your case, not necessarily correct.

Comment: @Domi I would allow to store whole file because it seems small, and this approach feels like more general and reusable, which I find important part when designing code. Also OP seems to be kinda of lost in problem. So I decided to put some OOP conept for educational purpose. In regard of `magic_number` I said it could be answered this way, I think it was obvious this was made as a sarcastic bad example. I find it a little less reliable than fixed line length. The only difference is whether the number of line is known. You shown the general idea how to calculate it.