# Counting lines, numbers, and characters in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I got an assignment today that requires that I read text in from a file, count the  number of lines, characters, and words, and return it in a specific format.

Just to be clear - I need to read in this text file:

```
"I must not fear.
Fear is the mind-killer.
Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration.
I will face my fear.
I will permit it to pass over me and through me.
And when it has gone past I will turn the inner eye to see its path.
Where the fear has gone there will be nothing... only I will remain"
  Litany Against Fear, Dune by Frank Herbert
```

and have it output like so:

```
1)"I must not fear.[4,17]
2)Fear is the mind-killer.[4,24]
3)Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration.[8,56]
4)I will face my fear.[5,20]
5)I will permit it to pass over me and through me.[11,48]
6)And when it has gone past I will turn the inner eye to see its path.[16,68]
7)Where the fear has gone there will be nothing... only I will remain"[13,68]
8)      Litany Against Fear, Dune by Frank Herbert[7,48]
```

Now, I've written something that will accept the file, it counts the number of lines properly, but I have 2 major issues - 1. How do I get the text from the file to appear in the output? I can't get that at all. My word count doesn't work at all, and my character count is off too. Can you please help?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

void main()
{
    int numChars = 0;
    int numWords = 0;
    int numLines = 0;
    int state = 0;
    int test = 0;

    FILE *doesthiswork;

    doesthiswork = fopen("testWords.in", "r");
    state = OUT;

    while ((test = fgetc(doesthiswork)) != EOF) 
    {
        ++numChars;
        if ( test == '\n') 
        {
            ++numLines;
            if (test == ' ' || test == '\t' || test == '\n')
            {      
                state = OUT;
            } 
            else if (state == OUT)
            {
                state = IN;
                ++numWords;
            }

         }
         printf("%d) I NEED TEXT HERE. [%d %d]\n",numLines, numWords, numChars);
     }

}
```

Comment: I would read a line at a time rather than a character at a time.

Comment: The Mentat's mantra is way more appropriate for programmers... Anyway, your *word* count is off because you should reset the associated variables to their initial state after reading the `\n` (what you have now) or before reading a new line (what Musa suggests).

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but how would I make it read a line at a time?

Comment: It *is*; this can easily be found elsewhere. Any of the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372813/reading-one-line-at-a-time-in-c should do for starters.

Answer (score 2):

1. It will be better if you use **getline()** function to read each line from the file.
2. And after reading the line process it using **strtok()** function. With this you will get the number of words in the line and save it in a variable.
3. Then process each variable and get the number of characters.
4. Output the line number, number of words and the number of characters.

Then read another line and so on.

Comment: `getline` also automatically provides you with the number of characters read as its return. Then you can simply assign a pointer to the buffer and count the number of spaces with `while (*ptr != 0) { if (*ptr == ' ') cnt++; ptr++; } words = cnt + 1;` and you have your words as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. *How do I get the text from the file to appear in the output?*
   It should be stored there by preparing a buffer.
2. *My word count doesn't work at all, and my character count is off too.*
   Order in which the test is wrong.

fix like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

int main(){
    int numChars = 0;
    int numWords = 0;
    int numLines = 0;
    int state = OUT;
    int test;
    char buffer[1024];
    int buff_pos = 0;
    FILE *doesthiswork;

    doesthiswork = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    state = OUT;

    while((test = fgetc(doesthiswork)) != EOF) {
        ++numChars;
        buffer[buff_pos++] = test;
        if(test == ' ' || test == '\t' || test == '\n'){
            state = OUT;
            if(test == '\n') {
                ++numLines;
                --numChars;//no count newline
                buffer[--buff_pos] = '\0';//rewrite newline
                printf("%d)%s[%d,%d]\n", numLines, buffer, numWords, numChars);
                buff_pos = 0;
                numWords = numChars = 0;
            }
         } else {
            if(state == OUT){
                state = IN;
                ++numWords;
            }
         }
    }
    fclose(doesthiswork);
    if(buff_pos != 0){//Input remains in the buffer.
        ++numLines;
        buffer[buff_pos] = '\0';
        printf("%d)%s[%d,%d]\n", numLines, buffer, numWords, numChars);
    }
    return 0;
}
```