# Using fscanf to read text then printing that text into a file using fprintf

Tags: c

So the goal for my program is to read some text from a file, have it encoded into another text file, and then have the inside letters of the word scrambled, so i need each word encoded separately, as opposed to in a string, so that i can end up being able to do this later. So far i have:

```
#define INPUT_FILENAME    ("A6P1_2016_TestingSherlock.txt")
#define OUTPUT_FILENAME     ("EncodeMe.txt")

void process_file(FILE* ifp, FILE* ofp) {
printf("Begin file processing\n");
char word[100];
while(fscanf(ifp, "%s", word) != EOF){
    fprintf(ofp, "%s ", word);
}

printf("End file processing\n");
}
```

The text that i'm taking from the Input file is as follows

```
Project Gutenberg The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes, by Arthur Conan Doyle
This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with
almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or
re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.net
```

And in the EncodeMe text file, i just get everything printed on one line. Help please?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read a whole line at a time, and use `strtok` to get the individual words from the line.

Comment: @user3121023 Oops, i forgot to mention that i need each word encoded seperately, instead of in a string. I used that exact code earlier, but i wouldn't be able to edit the words as easily

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", word);
```

if you want each word on a new line

Comment: But i dont want everything on its own line either, i want it printed exactly how the text looks from the input file.

Comment: then read the whole line at once, print it, then chop into words. heres how to read line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372813/reading-one-line-at-a-time-in-c