# search 2 different words in one line of a txt file in C program

Tags: c, string, search

I'm new to C and I was given a .txt file with data like this:

1. ID date time name country
2. 43 12/2 01:18 Amy AB
3. 347 12/12 12:30 Amy BC
4. 95 10/1 10:00 Bob AB
5. ...

Name will be equal to Amy/Bob/Cathy only and

Country will be equal to AB/BC/BD/DE only

I need to read the file and do the following things:

Example 1, I need to search the .txt file for Amy with country = AB and count how many number of data satisfy this situation

Example 2, search for Amy with country = DE and count

I don't have any idea about how to check for name and country at the same time, and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int i;
    char s[10];
    while(scanf("%s", s)==1){
         if (strcmp(s,"Amy")==0){
             if (strcmp(s,"AB")==0){
                 ++i;
             }
         }        
    }
```

I think the second if should not use s to compare with "AB" but what can I do?
Please help and thanks!

Comment: C is not C++. Don't spam tags

Comment: Can you share the snippet of the .txt file?

Comment: `strcmp(s, ...` can not  be `== 0` with  both "Amy" and "AB"

Comment: You can apply `strstr` with the substring `"Amy AB"`, to the whole line read with `fgets`.

Comment: read one line at a time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372813/reading-one-line-at-a-time-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your lines are always in the following format:

```
43 12/2 01:18 Amy AB

int int/int int:int string string
```

You can use `scanf` to parse the line:

```
scanf("%*d %*d/%*d %*2d:%*2d %s %s", name, country);
```

Where `name` and `country` are two buffers with enough space to store the data.

---

Example:

```
const char* s = "43 12/2 01:18 Amy AB";
char name[16]; char country[16];
sscanf(s, "%*d %*d/%*d %*2d:%*2d %s %s", name, country);

assert(strcmp(name, "Amy") == 0);
assert(strcmp(country, "AB") == 0);
```

[**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/n79OmP935eGftxZW)

---

Another possible solution could use [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) to locate the position of a particular substring *(names and countries, in your case)* inside the input.